# Best way to select random array element avoiding exclusion list

Tags: algorithm

What is the most elegant/efficient way to select a random position in an n*n matrix excluding a set of positions?

**Example:** Imagine a chess board, so **n=8** and there are **8*8 = 64** total positions. There are 3 pawns at positions (0, 0), (5, 3), (7, 4). The task is to select a random position that is not already occupied by the pawns.

This is what I came up with:

```
def get_random_position(n, occupied_positions):
    while True:
        random_position = (random.choice(range(n)), random.choice(range(n)))
        if random_position not in occupied_positions:
            return random_position
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unoccupied_random_position = get_random_position(8, [(0, 0), (5, 3), (7, 4)])
    print(unoccupied_random_position)
```

Time complexity is constant for n and linear with the number of occupied_cells. So if 90% cells are already occupied, the loop will iterate longer.

Is there are better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it is clear that you cannot do better than a worst case of *O(m)*, where *m* is the number of cells in the matrix, i.e. *m=n²*, where *n* is the width of the matrix: in the worst case all cells except one are occupied, you will need at least to look at each of those *m-1* coordinates.

I should also mention here that in your code `random_position not in occupied_positions` is not a constant operation. Each time that list is iterated to find a match.

Here is an alternative:

You could derive the number of free cells, produce a random number up to that limit, and then iterate the occupied cells to adapt that number (incrementally) to point to an actually free cell. In this process the number maps uniquely to an x and y coordinate.

For this to be efficient, we must assume that the list of occupied cells is already sorted.

Here is how that could be coded:

```
def get_random_position(n, occupied_positions):
    rnd = random.randint(0, n*n - 1 - len(occupied_positions))
    for (row, col) in occupied_positions:
        if rnd < row*n+col:
            break
        rnd += 1
    return (rnd // n, rnd % n)
```

This code runs in *O(k)*, where *k* is the size of the `occupied_positions` list. If we cannot guarantee that this list is sorted, then we need to sort it first, and this then determines the overall time complexity, i.e. *O(klogk)*.

Comment: Interesting approach, I did think about flattening the array but didn't think about this approach, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of choosing a random position and checking if it's occupied, first scan the board to see which positions are open. Create a list of those spots. This is `O(n)` where n is the number of total board spaces. Then, select a random element from *only* the open spots. Notice that when you only have a few open slots, the random selection still only picks from a space of a few spaces, and you will only ever have to random sample once.

Comment: Scanning the board to see which positions are open is not going to be O(n) because each position has to checked against the entire list of occupied positions, isn't it ?